# Can we use zookeeper to store offset in kafka apache metamodel

Tags: apache-kafka, metamodel, apache-metamodel

Apache MetaModel kafka consumer not working for zookeepers offset storage.
I am using Apache MetaModel 5.1 and kafka version 0.10.2.1. I am facing issue with kafka consumer(metamodel internal consumer) as its not consuming any messages from topic
my test environment kafka offset storage is zookeeper. when I tried with changing offset storage to KAFKA(on different environment), consumer worked fine.
As of now I don't want to change offset storage to kafka so is there any other way to fix this issue on Apache MetaModel kafka consumer side?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to change offset storage to Kafka please?

Comment: There is no specific reason. Right now everything is implemented with zookeeper and we are not ready to migrate to kafka yet. We might migrate it in future, but right now I want to work it around zookeeper only.

Comment: Since you also asked in the Apache MetaModel JIRA, I suggest we take that conversation there. Please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/METAMODEL-1198